# What are the differences between Custom Elements v0 and v1?

Tags: html, web-component, custom-element

What are the differences between Custom Elements v0 and v1?

See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) before using [v1](http://caniuse.com/#search=custom%20elements%20v1) or even [v0](http://caniuse.com/#search=custom%20elements%20v0).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

v1 replaces v0 which was an experimental try.

v0 was a [Google-only proposed specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-custom-elements-20160226/) while v1 is a WHATWG Web Standard [adopted by all major browser vendors](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements#historysupport) (implemented in Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Edge and partially in Safari).

More details on some Internet publications:

- [All about HTML Custom Elements](https://github.com/shawnbot/custom-elements) (v0 and v1).
- [What's New in Custom Elements](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/179IRXRFmDGb3P60OVsoAIsElcaOp__5EuIWLcL8oNos/) (from one of the author).

If you're new at Custom Elements, [forget v0](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/).